# Reliable implementation of NotificationListenerService possible?

Tags: android, notifications

I'm wandering around the NotificationListenerService, and could read and test tons of examples, tips, and tricks, a lot from here at SO...

But the implementation of a reliable NotificationListenerService seems far to be something real: from Kitkat to Marshmallow, across various devices, it looks like it's a wish to get it working properly without having to either need to reboot the phone, or ask more than once to enable access in the Secure Setting, and even with this, it does not trigger its onNotificationPosted method for sure each time a Notification lands !

My various tries on my devices are reflecting all that I could read: sometimes working, sometimes not, with same code, same device, rebooting makes it work during 1 or 2 notifications then it's gone... etc. 
I can't believe there is no reliable way to use this service (?)

A bottle in the sea: did anyone achieve a reliable way to implement this NotificationListenerService - by reliable I mean like on a production environment?

Thanks for reading

***EDIT***

As asked I can share some code, but it's nothing more that all can be found everywhere :

Manifest :

```
<service
            android:name=".services.NLService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Then the service itself :

```
public class NLService extends NotificationListenerService {

    private String TAG = "NLService";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i(TAG, "**********  onCreate");

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {

        Log.i(TAG, "**********  onNotificationPosted");
        Log.i(TAG, "ID :" + sbn.getId() + "\t" + sbn.getNotification().tickerText + "\t" + sbn.getPackageName());
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        Log.i(TAG, "********** onNOtificationRemoved");
        Log.i(TAG, "ID :" + sbn.getId() + "\t" + sbn.getNotification().tickerText + "\t" + sbn.getPackageName());
    }
}
```

And in the main Activity the service is started or we ask the user to enable the setting if needed :

```
if (!Utilities.hasNotificationAccess(this)) 
{
     Intent intent = new Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS");
     startActivity(intent);
     Log.i(TAG,"hasNotificationAccess NO");
}
else
{
    Log.i(TAG,"hasNotificationAccess YES");
    Intent mServiceIntent = new Intent(this, NLService.class);
    startService(mServiceIntent);
}
```

I get the OnCreate but the onNotificationPosted are working quite rarely.
On Android 6 it does just never trigger onNotificationPosted although the service is well created...

Comment: All of Android Wear's notifications are built off of a `NotificationListenerService`, so it appears to work for others. Do you have any code or particular devices you've had issues with?

Comment: Ok added some code in the question. But this may not be much helpful... Maybe Android Wear has stronger methods we don't have in a classic phone app... ?

Comment: Not working so well on Android Wear : http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-note-4/482332-notification-access-getting-turned-off.html#post4204836

Comment: i got some notification twice how can i filter its a big problem ?